# Setting margins in percentage

Tags: html, css, margins

I have this code which works nicely the only thing that I can't figure out is to get the spacings equal between all the squares.  Maybe the code explains it better then words. And here is a mockup with fixed pixel layout of 1465px width, as a example. [Mockup site](http://www.drummersantana.nl)

```
<div class="Content">
  <div class="ContLft">
    <div class="itemXL">
      <div class="itemXLcnt"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ContRght">
    <div class="itemL">
      <div class="itemLcnt"></div>
    </div>
     <div class="itemL">
      <div class="itemLcnt"></div>
    </div>
     <div class="itemL">
      <div class="itemLcnt"></div>
    </div>
     <div class="itemL">
      <div class="itemLcnt"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

/*css*/

```
.Content {
display: block;
width: 100%;
}

.ContLft {
float: left;
margin-right: 1.37305%;
width: 48.6269%;
}

.ContRght {
float: left;
width: 50%;
}

.itemXL {
background-color: #f4f4f4;
margin-bottom: 24px;
margin-right: 24px;
padding: 24px;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}

.itemXL:before{
content: "";
display: block;
padding-top: 100%;  /* initial ratio of 1:1*/
}

.itemL::before {
content: "";
display: block;
padding-top: 100%;
}

.itemL {
background-color: #f4f4f4;
float: left;
margin-bottom: 2.7461%;
margin-left: 2.7461%;
padding: 24px;
width: 47.2539%;
}

.itemLcnt {
position:relative;  
}

.itemXLcnt {
position:relative;
}
```

Comment: You're missing the `</div>` to close `.ContLft`

Comment: I'm sorry that's a copy and paste mistake, but thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, you can check it here jsfiddle.net/SanMoll/5egfry4h. I forgot that you have to subtract the margins from the width of the div's. The trick is simple 2 divs at 50% in a containing div at 100%, then the content divs nested in those 50% divs; the big one has a size of 96% and margin of 2% while the left square content divs have a width of 46% and allso a margin of 2% (50% minus 2x2%=46%).

But in the end you have scalable proportional squares, wich I like!

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- As Drew points out, your markup is missing a closing tag for the div.
- You need to use right margin on your smaller items
- Those smaller items are too wide which is forcing them to wrap each one to a new line instead of the look you want.
- Probably something else but it's just easier to paste it working. :-P

Divs:

```
<div class="Content">
  <div class="ContLft">
    <div class="itemXL">
      <div class="itemXLcnt"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
  <div class="ContRght">
    <div class="itemL">
      <div class="itemLcnt"></div>
    </div>
     <div class="itemL">
      <div class="itemLcnt"></div>
    </div>
     <div class="itemL">
      <div class="itemLcnt"></div>
    </div>
     <div class="itemL">
      <div class="itemLcnt"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
.Content {
     display: block;
     overflow: auto;
     width: 100%;
}

.ContLft {
     float: left;
     margin-right: 1.37305%;
     width: 48.6269%;
}

.ContRght {
     float: left;
     width: 50%;
}

.itemXL {
     background-color: #F4F4F4;
     margin-bottom: 24px;
     margin-right: 24px;
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
}

.itemXL:before {
     content: "";
     display: block;
     padding-top: 100%;
}

.itemL:before {
     content: "";
     display: block;
     padding-top: 100%;
}

.itemL {
     background-color: #F4F4F4;
     float: left;
     margin-bottom: 2.7461%;
     margin-right: 2.7461%;
     padding: 24px;
     width: 38.5%;
}

.itemLcnt {
     position: relative;
}

.itemXLcnt {
     position: relative;
}
```

Music (fiddle joke?): http://jsfiddle.net/bbvqofuq/

P.S. You might want to come up with a more consistent width setting. The percentages are going to cause it to jump around. Take a page (website joke?) from the example you provided and fix your widths for your elements or set them in a different manner. If you play with the fiddle I linked to and expand and contract the width of the result pane, you will see what I am talking about.

Comment: Thanks Dave, your fiddle sounds good :-), The thing is I want to keep the smaller squares in proportion of the bigger one. Meaning the smaller ones are a quarter in size of the bigger one so the line up nicely. I'm trying the Marcotte formula so the design will be responsive. I guess my math isn't that good, but I'll give it a other try. It's a bit like this one http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/MpXYr/3/embedded/result/. Anyways I will update this post when I got it right. Thanks again!

Comment: I got it, you can check it here http://jsfiddle.net/SanMoll/5egfry4h/. The trick is simple 2 divs at 50% in a containing div at 100%, then the content divs nested in those 50% divs; the big one has a size of 96% and margin of 2% while the left square content divs have a width of 46% and allso a margin of 2%. I think this is a beautiful design, maybe I should change the name of this topic so people can find this styling?

Comment: Looks great. It definitely is a good, yet simple appearing, design. If you change the topic, keep it a question so it's still relevant to SO and make sure it also pertains to the question asked.